# Conditional compilation and template

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose, I have a code:

```
template <typename T>
class C {
public:
    T f() { return m_result; }
    void todo() { m_result = doit<T>(); }
private:
    T m_result;
};
```

If `T` is `void`, I want to return `void` and have no `m_result` at all.
But, the compiler does not allow instantiate a `void` type.
One of decision is to create a specialization.

```
template <> class C<void> { /* ... */ }
```

But I don't what to support the almost identical code.
How can I don't instantiate `m_result`?
I can use C++17. Thanks!

Comment: If you can use `c++17`, you can wrap the `return` in a constexpr if.

Comment: try with `if constexpr`.

Comment: You cannot have an instance of `C` with `T = void` because you have a data member of type `T` and `void` is an imcomplete type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could place the data in a base class, then use `if constexpr`:

```
template<class T>
struct C_data{
    T m_result;
    };
template<>
struct C_data<void>{
    };

template<class T>
class C: C_data<T>
  {
  static constexpr auto is_void = std::is_same_v<T,void>;
  public:
  auto f(){
     if constexpr(is_void)
        return this->m_result;
     else
        return;
     }
  void todo(){
     if constexpr(is_void)
       this->m_result = doit<T>();
     else
        doit<T>();
     }
   };
```

But it can be argued that a the specialization of the class C is cleaner since all member of a template class should depend on all the template parameter (otherwise you should split your class in order to avoid code bloat).

So I would prefer to fully specialize C, and make part of the class C that are independent of T, a base class of C:

```
class C_base{
    //any thing that is independent of T;
    };
template<class T>
class C: public C_base{
    //any thing that depend on T
    };
template<>
class C<void>: public C_base{
    //any thing that depend on T;
    };
```

You could also specialize member funtion by member function, but I find it less clean.

You will find this last code structure in almost all headers of standard library implementations.

Comment: You can use `std::is_void_v` instead of `std::is_same_v`.

Comment: @DanielLangr I would never do such a thing! This do not bring any thing, obviously any combination of std::is_same_v<a_type,...> could be defined. This is a pathological behavior of programmer to multiply the object more than necessary: it just save me to type 3 letters, but put a charge on my own memory and on the compiler.

Comment: What??? `std::is_void` is likely implemented somewhat as `std::is_same<void, typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>`. So what is the difference?

Comment: @DanielLangr So it is even worst than what I imagined! At least if they had named it is_rcved_void there would be a tip to say, hey look at the definition of this.

Comment: I kind of still don't understand your motivation. If you care so much about burdening a compiler, then it would make sense to write `is_void` or even `is_same` by yourself and consequently, you wouldn't need to include and process `type_traits` header.

Comment: @DanielLangr `is_same_v` is implemented in more than 3 characters, its name clearly says what it does, and their is good chance I find it oftenly in my code. `is_void` is a micro layer on `is_same_v`, its name is mistaking us about what it does, their much less chance that I find it in my code. So if I find it, and hopefully I reminber that it is badly named, I will have to check what it means, so I will need to see at its implementation, finding where one has put this unusefull definition, etc... It just would tired me less not to have to reminber that their are mistakingly named entity in ->

Comment: -> the STL, and to see one time in my code, directly its definition, since their are so poor chance I use it!

Comment: @DanielLangr, And is this action of removing the cv qualifier helpfull here? I don't think so, while volatile will certainly make no sense for T, const will probably change deeply or make its class unusefull. So the right thing to do here is to concept check that T is not CV qualified, neither is a reference nor a function or array type: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<T,std::decay_t<T>>)`.

Comment: All right, thanks for explanation of your opinion. Just why to "see its implementation" to find out what it means? Meaning/functionality of `std::is_void` is clearly given by the Standard (e.g., Section 20.9.4.1 for C++11).

Comment: So I will have to find it out in the C++ standard. This is my opnion indeed. Actualy not focused only on the C++ standard library but also for example on libc, which a small layers around system calls that spread static state all around, making system calls inconsistent, causing lot of trouble, etc... and finaly even cause design mistake in the C++ standard, for consistency with libc!!!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> T doit() { return T{}; }

template <typename T> struct result_policy { T m_result; };
template <> struct result_policy<void> { };

template <typename T>
class C : private result_policy<T> {
  public:
    T f(){
      if constexpr (!std::is_void_v<T>)
        return result_policy<T>::m_result;
    }

    void todo() {
      if constexpr(!std::is_void_v<T>)
        result_policy<T>::m_result = doit<T>();
    }
};

int main() {
  C<int> ci;
  ci.todo();
  int i = ci.f();

  C<void> cv;
  cv.todo();
  cv.f();
}
```

I used `if constexpr` from C++17 to work with `m_result` and stored `m_result` into policy struct only for non-void types due to partial template specialization.

Comment: This is an overuse of `if constexpr`, a specialization is cleaner and less prone to a basic mistake: declaring member inside class template that are independent of the template parameter.

Comment: Don't understand. In your solution `if constexpr` is twice, in mine twice as well.

Comment: I just use the version with `if constepxr` to point out that the second example code in my answer (which was actualy its first idea and does not use constexpr if) is the best idea.

Comment: @DanielLangr, thank you too. Your solution must be accepted too but you made the mistake not calling todo<T> for T=void and thus I've chosen Oliv

Comment: @AlexeySubbota No problem. I skipped it since in you original code, `todo` was called to assign result to `m_result`. Which has no sense, if there is no `m_result`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++17, then try with `if constexpr`, `std::is_same_v<>` and `std::conditional_t<>`:

```
#include <type_traits>

// auxiliary variable template for checking against void type in a more readable way
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_void_v = std::is_same_v<T, void>;

// auxiliary alias template for determining the type of the data member
// in order to prevent the compiler from creating member of type "void"
// so if T = void --> data member type as "int"
template<typename T>
using member_type_t = std::conditional_t<!is_void_v<T>, T, int>;

template <typename T>
class C{
public:
    T f(){ return (T)m_result; } // no problem if T = void

    void todo() {
       if constexpr(!is_void_v<T>)
          m_result = doit<T>();
       else
          doit<T>();
    }
private:
    member_type_t<T> m_result;
};
```

Actually, as of C++17 there is already a `std::is_void_v<>` variable template with `type_traits`.

Comment: `std::enable_if` takes only 2 template arguments, doesn't it?

Comment: For at least f, you can write "return (T)m_result;" and it will work even for void.

Comment: @DanielLangr it does.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb great!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb "it works" is not an excuse to use it. It's _terrible_!

Comment: @YSC Bad. I guess if I asked now, after showing off such gross things, I would stand no chance anymore for a job in Paris (I'm in Frankfurt anyway and not looking).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb your level of sarcasm is too strong for me to stand. You win.

Comment: Nice solution, just it has the drawback that for `void`-case you have an unused member variable, which occupies some memory.